# Make content force DIV grow vertically until max-height is reached, and then grow horizontally

Tags: jquery, html, css, word-wrap

I have a div with some text. This div has `min-height`, `min-width`, `max-height` and `max-width`.
I want to prioritize height in wrapping text, that means until there is an ability to stretch
the div vertically (height < max-height), the text should be wrapped evenly to fill the height.
Then if max-height is reached, the wrapping should be arranged in the way to fill width until
max-width allows to do that. If both max-height and max-width is reached, text should be wrapped 
as usual.

Unfortunatelly, my text is not wrapped while `width` < `max-width`, and I can't find a way to make it
be wrapped by height.

Please someone, give me an advice.

Thanks.

Comment: CSS can't *prioritze* one dimension over another...at not the way I think you are suggesting. JS **might** be able to do something but it sounds like an odd request to me in the first place....I can't think of a use-case for this.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/8L08e8dh/

Comment: In other words, the design requires the div to be on the left of a page, I would say it is the only div on the page. And the text inside the div should not cause verticall scrollbar while it is possible, and being on the left side with certain width is prioritized. But If we can't fit text vertically on the page, we should use horizontal space while it is possible, and only then we can use horizontall scrolling. I hope this make sense.

Comment: As Paulie_D stated it sounds like something you cannot do with CSS. Perhaps there may be something if you use vh and vw for units instead of pixels and percent

Comment: Håvard Brynjulfsen, do you mean that vh and vw should be used for min-height, min-width, max-height and max-width? For frankly speaking, I don't quite understand how it can affect textwrapping priority. If it's possible could you give a sample? To be clearer I would like to say that font-size should be constant, we just don't know the amount of text (how many words) that div is going to contain. Therefore I mean textwrapping (not fitting font-size).

Comment: I tried my theory and it didn't work. I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish, but I guess it's a JS problem, and my knowledge only extends as far as basic CSS

Comment: Js, jQuery is acceptable. if not inconvenient to you, please give an example. I would be very grateful.

Comment: I don't know if I understand. Isn't this demo working as you need? [https://jsfiddle.net/chimos/83ra9ysh/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/chimos/83ra9ysh/2/)
The text content makes the div reach its max-height and max-width and then scroll apears. You can try deleting text to see that the div becomes smaller.

Comment: Ok. The content first forces the div becoming wider and then taller and you want it the other way, first reach the max-height and if there's more content then reach the max width. So in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chimos/83ra9ysh/4/), the div on the right side should be min-width and taller than it is, since the content would fit. Is it so?

Comment: One of the commenters couldn't think of a use case - that isn't a valid response, as the originator has got a use case. I have the same issue, and my use case is a custom button with multi-line text, where I would like the text on the button to use the available vertical space before it starts increasing the width of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it does moreless what you need, using javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('div.weird').each(function(){ 

        var el = $(this);
        var dW = +$(el).css('width').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
        var maxW = +$(el).css('max-width').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
        var maxH = +$(el).css('max-height').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');

        var i;
        for (i=0; i+dW < maxW; i++) {
            if ( this.offsetHeight < this.scrollHeight ) {
                dW = dW+i;
                $(el).css({'width': dW+'px', 'height': maxH+'px'});
            }
        }

    });

});
```

CSS:

```
.weird {
    background: #eee; /*not needed*/
    width: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 400px;
    max-width: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left; /*not needed*/
}
```

For this approach is needed to start defining a fixed width for the DIV, then the width incresses pregressively until there's no overflow or until reaches the max-width.

In this example you can see two DIVs with the same properties but containing different ammounts of text:
https://jsfiddle.net/chimos/83ra9ysh/25/

Comment: Yes, It nearly does. The issue is that when we get height >= max-height, it shouldn't decrease, but unfortunatelly in your sample, when you set width = auto, height contracts. If height reach max-height then it should stay there.

Comment: @Andrei  I edited my answer. I hope now it works as you described.

Comment: This solution is very close to perfect! You're genious, scrollHeight and offsetHeight seem to be what I need. Thank you very much for your response. I want to upvote your answer, but unfortunatellly I don't have enough reputation. I will try again when someone upvotes my question.

Comment: Better than upvoting, you could mark it as accepted if it answered your question (the green check icon). I'm glad it helped. Cheers